# Something wrong with my cmputer’s System variable

Tags: windows, variables, path, system

[image]
these are my variable：users' and system's, and when i try to add a variable to system variable I find that I cant open the Path like that:
[image]
It only displays like this:[image]

Forgive my Chinese verion and I think you can read it by your experience

I want my system variable(Path) be like the normal type whitch can add a lot of variables

Answer (score 1):

Ok，I solved it by myself.
Just delete this "Path" and create a new one
and load the codes below then run it as bat:
chcp 65001&cls

REM 备份当前环境变量
echo 当前环境变量：
echo %Path%

echo 永久设置Hadoop、scala、Java、 go、spark、zookeeper环境变量

SETX /M GO_ROOT "C:\Go"

SETX /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"

SETX /M HADOOP_HOME "C:\hadoop"

SETX /M SCALA_HOME "C:\scala-2.11.8"

SETX /M SPARK_HOME "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

SETX /M ZOOKEEPER_HOME "C:\zookeeper-3.4.14"

SETX /M Path "%Path%;%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\jars;%SCALA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GO_ROOT%\bin"

echo 修改完成, 即将重启文档管理器explorer
pause

REM 重启explorer.exe使环境变量立即生效
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
echo ================================================
echo 开始重启“explorer.exe”进程
start explorer.exe

paus